# Displaying elements works while condition is true

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am playing with js and html.
I`ve imported elements from a database into my page and now I want to filter them by some user inputs.
I was thinking to hide all, then to check the condition and show which are compatible with what user wants.
It works perfectly fine, until if statement finds first "false".

Ex: If I have 5 products, and if results: true, true, false, false, true; in my page will be visible just first two, even if at the end is one more.

```js
 window.onload=function(){
 
    let btn = document.getElementById("filtrare");
    
    btn.onclick = function(){
        let pret_utilizator = document.getElementById("i_text").value;
        let pret_utilizator_range = document.getElementById("range_pret").value;
        let articole = document.getElementsByClassName("art-produs");
        let checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
        let stock1 = document.getElementsByClassName("stock");
        let i=0;
        let culori = document.getElementsByClassName("culori");
        
        for(let art of articole){
            art.style.display = "none";
            
            let pret_site = parseInt(art.getElementsByClassName("pret")[0].innerHTML);
            let pret_site_range = parseInt(art.getElementsByClassName("pret")[0].innerHTML);
            let conditie_pret = pret_site <= pret_utilizator;  
            let conditie_pret_range = pret_site_range <= pret_utilizator_range;

            console.log(culori[i].innerHTML);
           
            let conditie_stock = false;
            if(checkbox.checked && Boolean.parse(stock1[i].innerHTML)) {
                conditie_stock = true;
            }
            
            i=i+1;

            let conditie_afisare = conditie_pret && conditie_pret_range && conditie_stock;
           
            if(conditie_afisare) {
                art.style.display ="block";
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That'll be cool if you add code snippet here!

Comment: kindly provide us with what you have tried so far.
Also consider going through: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the js-code. Please add also some dummy html for testing and a reproducable example...